# How to Limit the DOM manipulation in jQuery - appending elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am following the "best practices" concerning the DOM manipulation topic. I am having a problem though. Before, my code was:

```
for(var i=0;i<size;++i){
    var $li = $('<li/>',{some propertie..}).data(some values);
    $ul.append($li);
}
```

After reading a bit of performance tips, I concluded that I need to replace this into:

```
var str_html = '';
for(var i=0;i<size;++i){
    var li  = '<li ...>...</li>';
    str_html += li;
}
$ul.append(str_html);
```

My question is, how can I add the data parameters in this second approach, the same way I was doing in the first one (for each li element)?
Thanks!

Comment: Why did you conclude that you *need* to replace this with a string-based approach? Do you actually have any performance problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery `1.4.3` you can set [`data attributes`<sup>have a read</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/). This would look like:

```
var str_html = '';
for(var i=0;i<size;++i){
   var li  = '<li data-somevalue="foobar">...</li>';
   str_html += li;
}
$ul.append(str_html);
```

jQuery will automatically pull all `data-` attributes into the elements data-expando. So you could access the above example with:

```
$('li').data('somevalue') // === foobar
```

You actually can put in any type of data into such an attribute, even `JSON decoded` object-string literals (which automatically get parsed by jQuery):

```
'<li data-somevalue="{'foo':'Barrrrr'}">...</li>';
```

is translated into

```
$('li').data('somevalue').foo // === Barrrr
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the [jquery template API](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DocumentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) (the blog post is written by Resig himself, so the template API mentioned will most likely use DocumentFragment).

It is the best way to append DOM Elements without using innerHTML. Although innerHTML will almost always be the fastest method.

If $ul is an already existing Element in the DOM Tree, you might speed things up by removing it from the tree, adding LI elements to it, and re-append it. This will however not guarantee better performance: using a profiling tool is the only way to measure the impact.